# App not installed error when upgrading app

Tags: android, apk

When trying to manually install an apk (v2.0) over an .apk (v1.0), I get the error "APP not installed" error on my device.

I should note that both of the .apk are the same app, only the version is upgraded.

I am also using release version of the apk and I don't want to uninstall the existing app (just upgrade).

Can anyone help me identify what might be the cause of this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Check you have installed release version before. If you installed debug version you cannot install release to debug or visa versa.

Comment: Make sure you have the same signature of application in both applications.

Answer (score 0):

upgrade app scenario works when the version code of both the apks should be different. The incoming version should have a higher VersionCode (not VersionName) than that of the existing app. Just Verify that versionCode of both the apps are different. This can be verified by play store console (for the existing build from play store) and app > build.gradle

Comment: thank you for your response .I am sure have versioncode of apk v2.0 > versioncode of apk v1.0 .;

Comment: is the Keystore used for signing both the app same? I know you have mentioned that You have a release build but check as this can be a reason for an issue in upgrade scenarios.